# Capture browser network requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I want to capture the response of API calls the browser makes when loading data and validate that data for my automated tests. I am using webdriverio for my automation. Is there any way I can do this ?

[image: network traffic response]

Comment: You want to detect ajax responses all request?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus)
        },
    });
```

Comment: This is configuration for all ajax request not spesific ajax 
You can read about in therere https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: Also you can 
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  // Your code here
});